# Making whole plot transparent

Tags: plotting, opacity

Is it possible to make a whole plot (including axes etc) transparent using a simple command?

To compare some figures I want to be able to quickly show plots over each other with one or multiple of them being transparent, e.g. with:

```
opacity = 0.5;
Show[makePlotTransparent[referencePlot,opacity],otherPlot]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
plot1 = Plot[Sin[x^2]/x, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red];
plot2 = Plot[Sin[2 x]/x, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick];

Show[plot1, plot2]
```

[image]

```
makeTransparent[o_ : .2] := Show[# /. c_?ColorQ :> (Append[o] @ c),
    BaseStyle -> {FontOpacity -> o, LineOpacity -> o}] &;


Show[makeTransparent[] @ plot1, plot2]
```

[image]

**Update:** We can also use [`ImageCompose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageCompose.html) using `{plot1,.2}` as the second argument:

```
ImageCompose[Show[plot2, AxesStyle -> Opacity[0]], {plot1, .2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**For interactive control**

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

plot1 = Plot[Sin[x^2]/x, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red];
plot2 = Plot[Sin[2 x]/x, {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick];

Manipulate[
 Show[
  If[switch, plot2, plot1],
  If[switch, plot1, plot2] /. Opacity[_] :> Opacity[opac]],
 Row[{
   Control[{{opac, 0.5, "opacity"}, 0, 1, 0.05,
     Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Medium}],
   Spacer[10],
   Control[{{switch, False}, {True, False}}]}],
 TrackedSymbols :> {opac, switch}]
```

[image]